# I accidentally deleted hundreds of files involved with the iOS SDK - I hit "Move to Trash" instead. How can I reinstall these OS X api files?

Tags: ios, xcode

I deleted files from all sorts of frameworks - UIKit, Foundation, SystemConfiguration. I can see the files in my trash ban but there's no option to put them back in their original location.

Some of these file names include: uiselection.cpp, uiupdatehandler.cpp, usediids.cpp, etc...

Any help is greatly appreciateed

Comment: Delete Xcode and download it again? Might not be the fastest but it's sure to get everything back in the right place.

Comment: try to add them again in xcode? If it wont work just reinstall it as @fogmeister said.

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode didn't work. Installing Xcode nowadays is just a simple drag-and-drop into your applications folder. Would it actually make a difference if I deleted it first and then re-drag--and-drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Trash Can (if the files are still in there) and then select the files you want to restore and in the Finder, go to to the "File" menu and choose "Put Back".

If Put Back isn't enabled, that usually means the parent folder has also been deleted and Fogmeister's suggestion of re-installing Xcode is the way to go.

If the files are actually *deleted* and not in your Trash Can, then let this be a lesson to you to make use of Time Machine (which is built into MacOS).  All you need is a separate hard drive to serve as a backup device.

Comment: Reinstalling didn't help. When you drag-and-drop Xcode to your applications folder, does it do anything in the background to place these essential files where they need to be placed? I would assume not. And I'm also assuming all these essential files/frameworks are not contained within the Xcode.app package. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: The SDK is indeed kept inside the Xcode application package nowadays.  Unless you explicitly copied or moved them to some folder outside of Xcode, I'm still not precisely sure how you could have gotten yourself into the situation you're in.

Comment: Whoops - it's working now. Had to clean project. Thanks for your help.